# SpringMVC, c3p0, hibernate, JPA Application leaking Connections leads to Too Many Connections error

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, c3p0

I've googled and searched stackoverflow for a solution to my problem for over 4 hours now, reading and trying to learn what is happening but I have not come across a solution that pertains to my issue so apologies if this sounds like a duplicate, I'll try my best to explain exactly what is happening so I can get some insight into the inner workings of c3p0.

I have a SpringMVC web application running on Tomcat with Hibernate, JPA, and C3P0 as my pooling resource. On page reload, the application as it stand makes a few calls to the database to get a random image and display it on the new page. The application runs fine for about 30 or so page reloads but always eventually crashes and I have to restart mysql in order for the application to work again, it gives the following error:

> Apr 04, 2015 12:21:55 PM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask run
>   WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@634d8e3d -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor101.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1114)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2493)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2311)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor43.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
>       at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner$TaskThread.run(ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner.java:255)

Here are pertaining files/configurations to give context to the problem:

spring.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.clathrop.infographyl.dao" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="infographylPU" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <!-- Connection properties -->
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/infographyl_db" />
    <property name="user" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="passwd" />
    <!-- Pool properties -->
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="3000" />
    <property name="loginTimeout" value="300" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="infographylPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.clathrop.infographyl.model.Infographic</class>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Here is what a basic query looks like, in this class I have an EntityManager as an instance variable and i close() the entityManager after every query is finished but it has no affect on the number of connections made in the database.

InfographicDaoImpl.java:

```
@Repository
public class InfographicDaoImpl implements InfographicDao{

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
@Transactional
public void insertInfographic(Infographic infographic){
    try{
        entityManager.persist(infographic);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }

}

@Override
public List<Infographic> findAllInfographics(){
    try{
        CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Infographic> cq = builder.createQuery(Infographic.class);

        Root<Infographic> root = cq.from(Infographic.class);
        cq.select(root);
        List<Infographic> igList = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
        return igList;
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}

@Override
public Infographic getRandomInfographic(Integer tableSize){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomIndex = rand.nextInt((tableSize-1)+1) + 1;

    try{
        CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Infographic> cq = builder.createQuery(Infographic.class);

        Root<Infographic> root = cq.from(Infographic.class);
        cq.select(root);
        cq.where(builder.equal(root.<Integer>get("id"), randomIndex));
        Infographic randomIg = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
        return randomIg;
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }


}

@Override
public Integer getRowCount(){
    try{
        Number result = (Number) entityManager.createNativeQuery("Select count(id) from infographics").getSingleResult();
        return result.intValue();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}

@Override
public List<Infographic> listInfographics(Integer startIndex, Integer pageSize){
    List<Infographic> igList = new ArrayList<Infographic>();

    String sStartIndex = Integer.toString(startIndex);
    String sPageSize = Integer.toString(pageSize);

    try{
        List list = entityManager.createNativeQuery("Select * from infographics limit " + sStartIndex + ", " + sPageSize).getResultList();
        for(Object ig : list){
            igList.add((Infographic) ig);
        }
        return igList;
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }


}
```

}

At this point I have a few questions as to what is happening in my application. The way I understand it is that c3p0 is handling connections made to the database and I thought that with a pooled connection, the connections made would be reused but instead I am getting a growing list of more connections when I look at the processlist in mysql. The number of connections keeps growing until the application finally throws the too many connection warning shown above. My question is why is c3p0 not reusing the connections? Am I missing a configuration somewhere to tell it to reuse the pre-existing connections? Why does entityManager.close() seemingly have no affect? If I am misunderstanding how to use hibernate and c3p0 please let me know what I am missing. Any help is greatly appreciate, thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

> SEVERE: The web application [/infographyl] appears to have started a thread named [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

I've narrowed down the problem to a memory leak that is being recognized when tomcat starts up and deploys the application in question. My issue now is trying to find what possible configuration (or missing config) is causing the issue.

My current workaround is to set the wait_timeout in my.cnf to kill processes/connections that are older than 5 seconds, this seems to be ok for now but it is not a sustainable solution and I'd like to know the correct way to close my connections.

UPDATE2:
com.mchange.* INFO log:

> Apr 05, 2015 10:57:30 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider
>   INFO: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
>   Apr 05, 2015 10:57:30 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource getPoolManager
>   INFO: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 1, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> z8kfsx98137ghpr10fde73|6aa74262, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> z8kfsx98137ghpr10fde73|6aa74262, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 3000, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/infographyl_db, lastAcquisitionFailureDefaultUser -> null, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 20, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]

Comment: how do you acquire the object 'entityManager'?

Comment: @SteveWaldman, thanks for the reply. The entityManager object is created when the InfographicDaoImp object is instantiated. I will update the code sample to give you a better idea. Is this the wrong way to create/access the entityManager?

Comment: Ok - is this always happening, or is this a production environement and you have found such problems happening occasionaly there?

Comment: @clathrop Yes there is. Wrong way is to create One and use it across the threads, or still using it after exception beeing throw etc. EntityManager.close() has effect for sure. Are there any other exceptions along ?

Comment: @Antoniossss, this is happening in my local test environment and it always happens like this. I have to restart mysql in order to continue to use the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, from everything that you've described, it sounds like your application is creating and then abandoning multiple c3p0 pools. You don't experience what would be the usual symptom of exhaustion of a single pool (application freezes). Instead, your app opens more Connections than maxPoolSize, and then fails when it hits server-side Connection limits. Unless your server things ~20 Connections is too many, you are likely to be creating more than one pool. Setting `wait_timeout` hides the problem, as the Connections of the abandonned DataSources get automatically close()ed, but it won't be a good solution. If you are making new DataSources for each client, you'll dramatically slow down rather than speed up your app, and if those DataSources are not close()ed (it seems they aren't, or you'd not accumulate open Connections), you'll create Thread and memory leaks.

So.

First, how are you logging things? Please make sure that `com.mchange.*` classes are logged at INFO, and check look for pool initiation messages. c3p0 dumps a large pool config message at INFO on DataSource initialization. Make sure you see at least one of those messages. Do you see them many times? Then that is the problem.

If I am right and you are opening then abandoning multiple c3p0 DataSources, the next question becomes why. Pooled DataSources in your app are embedded in an `EntityManagerFactory` object, of which there should be just one for the lifetime of your application. Spring makes things look easy, but it hides the details of how/when things are constructed, destroyed, etc. I think the key question you may have to answer is why/whether Spring is creating multiple EntityManagerFactory instances (or recreating the c3p0 DataSource multiple times within a single EntityManagerFactory).

p.s. c3p0 offers no "loginTimeout" config parameter.

Comment: thanks for much for the informative reply. Yes I do see many pool config messages from com.mchange.*, these occur every time I reload the page. When I reload the page, the application queries the database for a new image to show in the front end so ideally I want to be able to reload the page as many times as I want and if I understand correctly, not have to create a new c3p0 pool connection each time. I'll paste the logs for the c3p0 info log in my question to be sure we are talking about the same thing. How do you recommend going about finding out the underlying issue?

Comment: you see the log message you've pasted above repeated with each page reload?

Comment: Yep, definitely didn't seem like a good thing, now I know it's definitely not a good thing hah. I'm not sure if there is another file/configuration that I'm not showing that I should be, I thought I pasted everything relevant, if I'm missing something it could be found in my [github](github.com/clathrop/infographyl)

Comment: no. that's a very bad thing. you should see it once per app deploy. ie in a Tomcat app you should see it when you first startup the app (maybe delayed to a first page load), and then never again until you update the war file.

Comment: I'm accepting you answer as the best since you're most likely right in providing the area in which the error is resulting but I've yet to find the solution still. I'll keep hunting through logs and reading up on spring/c3p0 to see if I can find where I'm doing something wrong, thanks for your help!

Comment: (if you can't figure it out, i can provide a version of c3p0 instrumented to show the stack traces of the DataSource construction codepaths. It's going to involve a lot of hidden Spring stuff, which I wish I could be more helpful about.)

Comment: Hi Steve, that would be really helpful, right now I am trying to create a blank new project that incorporates everything I have in my application, just a dumbed down version to see it working properly and then apply what I know from that to my own application. So I would need JPA, Hibernate, springmvc, and c3p0 example application. If you have something like that readily available then I would love to take a look, if not, I can probably muster something up with some struggling :) thanks for your guidance.

Comment: so, if you are setup to deal with SNAPSHOT dependencies, try c3p0-0.9.6-pre1-SNAPSHOT, and where you currently use `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource` try `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.debug.ConstructionLoggingComboPooledDataSource`. Make sure you can see DEBUG level messages, for a logger called `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.debug.ConstructionLoggingComboPooledDataSource`. Every time this DataSource bean gets created, it will emit the stack trace of its creation into your logs at a DEBUG level. Maybe that helps you pick up some clues as to what's going wrong.

Comment: Hi Steven, I finally got it figured out. Turns out I was indeed configuring my application context/web context incorrectly, leading to wacky bean definitions and creations etc. I can't remember everything that I changed around to make it work since it was over a few days learning process but it's finally working perfectly. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution to my problem but I'm not quite sure it is the best approach.

I set wait_timeout in my.cnf to 5 seconds via:

```
[mysqld]
wait_timeout=5
```

This seems to be effective in destroying the sleeping processes that entityManager is creating and allowing me to run the app for extended periods of time without having to restart mysql.

My question now is, is this really the best and only way to deal with connections that are created by c3p0 + EntityManager? Why doesn't c3p0 destroy the connections or remove them on its own? Is this intended? Any clarification or discussion is appreciated. Thanks all :)

Comment: C3p0 works just fine, tested in couple production environements. You have to revise whole DB related code for not try-catch-finally blocks involwing EntityMnagers as this is the only way you can run out of connections.

Comment: As for the specification `wait_timetout` defalut value is 5 till 5.0.51 and 10 since 5.0.52. so you did not change nothing that wasnt there by default.

Comment: Without specifying the wait_timeout, the connection processes created by entityManager were in Sleep for well above 10 seconds, there was no default wait_timeout attribute in my.cnf when I went to update it. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "You have to revise whole DB related code for not try-catch-finally blocks involwing EntityMnagers as this is the only way you can run out of connections." At first you said I needed the try-catch-finally, now you're saying I shouldn't?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_connect_timeout. Defaults are set to values like above (defaults are not defined in cfg file). No, you  misunderstood, revise your code and add everywhere `try-catch-finally`, or at least `try-finally` where entity manager in involved.

Comment: I edited my code to show my entired InfographicDaoImpl which is the only place in my app that uses the entityManager, I've closed all instances of entityManager like you suggested but this has no affect which makes sense I guess if like you said is true that the container is handling the life cycle of the EntityManager through the @PersistenceContext, so why does it matter that I close them?

Comment: OK. So if that all you are doing with the db  it should be just fine. How are you testing that? JUnit (TestNG) or manually - run, send requests, get error? For now, everything should work so there must be something else we are missing here (I mean, some piece of code and/or configuration.

Comment: https://github.com/clathrop/infographyl here's a link to the project on my github, I've moved on to work on other parts of the app so there's more than what I stated in my original question. I really appreciate if you can find anything that I'm doing wrong, I'm a noob to springmvc and trying to learn as I go, if I'm missing/misunderstanding certain concepts please let me know so I can go read up on them and understand what it is I should be doing. Thanks man :)

Comment: As far as how I am testing it, I haven't been able to successfully connect to remote tomcat in debug mode with intellij, another mystery in and of itself so I have resorted to packaging a war and deploying to tomcat and using logs to debug the application.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that some of DB operations are causing exceptions. In such case Exception is thrown and the EntityManager is not closed as it should. Normally your db operations should looks like

```
        EntityManager em=getEntityManagerSomehow();
        try{
            do your stuff with db here
        }catch(Exception ex){ 
            handle exception here eg. log or rethrow.

          }finally{
           em.close();  // always close entity manager even if exception occures.
       }
```

In my opinion, if you refactor your code like shown abowe, problem will be fixed.

Comment: Hi Antoniossss, thanks for the reply. I tried what you suggested and it did not fix the problem, the mysql connections are still persisting and not being reused or closed. I looked up [some examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html) of using entityManager, and no where do they explicitely close the entityManager, I'm not sure if that's on purpose or done for brevity sake? It's not really clear what the best practice is.

Comment: Always close entity manager. But here you have container managed persistance context, so it should be fail-safe closed anyway by the container

Comment: u are leaking connections somewhere else

Comment: I think you're right, after digging through the logs I'm seeing a few stack traces like so: `SEVERE: The web application [/infographyl] appears to have started a thread named [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.` The problem is I don't know what could be causing this, possibly the way I have setup my persistenceContext and EntityManager? Is there anything else I should share that could show why this might be happening?